# Access Public Site VF Page and Controller with some data returned in url from Other Org or execute the JS method from VFpage based on Pageref.Param

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, force.com-sites, guest-user

Can anyone please help me with this, I have a public site in Org1 and it has a vf page,Standard controller in it. My requirement is when I pass some parameters and call the public site vf page from Org2 then in Org1 it will check if url has specific param or not. If it is there then it will call one JS function. Basically I want to execute the JS function in Org1 from org2 through Site URL.

```
  Date newd=Date.newInstance(1993, 05,01);
    PageReference pg= AccessPublicSiteVfPage.getpagrredirected('https://sitedev-hjdev.cs1.force.com/techsupport/TechnicalPrechat?','&idorg2','6548');
    return pg;//AccessPublicSiteVfPage.getpagrredirected in this method it is returning pageref.
```

But this doesn't do anything. Not even in the Org1 debug I can see this has redirected to Org1.
Please let me know how I can achieve this.

```
public with sharing class AccessPublicSiteVfPage {
    
   
    @AuraEnabled//From Visitor Org I am trying to execute Public site class
    public static void getSurfPin(String urlparam,String name,Date dob){
        PageReference pg=getpagrredirected(urlparam,name,dob);
    }

//urlparam=>Public site URL which has a vf page assigned in it    
public static PageReference getpagrredirected(String urlparam,String name,Date dob)
    {
        PageReference pinppage;
        try {
         if(String.isNotBlank(urlparam))
         {
            pinppage = new PageReference('urlparam' +'&name='+name+'&dob='+dob+'&pinId=');
            pinppage.setRedirect(false);
         }   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.debug('pinppage='+pinppage);
        return null;
    }
}
```

**My requirement is to execute the controller which is present in public site VF page so that I can execute one JS method in that controller** which will fire an event and that event can listen my community from markup in the advanced setting.
Basically I need a pin code generated from one of the app through user(who is above 60 age) and that pin needs to be sent to the live agent who is with him/her. But since they are old age person so I am trying to hit the site vf page url which generates the pin and automatically send that pin from user's end to me. But the problem is when user clicks on the vf page(public site VF page) button then it opens the page and inside it 2 buttons are there. Which user clicks on it and a code gets generated but it is not happening when I just redirect the url through apex i.e. no page navigation only workinng from backend on behalf of user to send the pin. The org's vf page's controller is not even getting called.

Comment: Hi Anony, could you please provide more insights into what `getpagrredirected` on class `AccessPublicSiteVfPage` does? Maybe sharing more of your code can give insights into what might be going wrong and can be changed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.